# Play *.srt subtitles in Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-media-player, subtitles

Is there a way to play [*.srt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip#SubRip_.srt_file_example) subtitles in Windows Media Player?

I've followed the instructions in [this](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/41466.aspx), by installing DirectVobSub and renaming the srt file to match the video filename, but the subtitles don't show up, WMP is configured to show subs when available.

Comment: It sounds like you're going to a lot of trouble to get it to work. Is there are particular reason that you *must* use WMP? Can you not use VideoLanClient instead? VLC natively loads `.srt` files and automatically shows them (you can press a key to turn them off).

Comment: I tried VLC but I face a [different problem](http://superuser.com/questions/441910/subtitles-in-vlc-are-displayed-as-question-marks/441914), anyway, I'm playing it with Media Player Classic and it works perfect. Anyway if there is a solution I'd like to hear about it, so I'll leave this question opened.

Comment: I would recommend you this [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpromedia/thread/77b3902b-0cf2-48d0-96a4-b859eb53a03f) article and also try out the solution on this [Forum thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/music-pictures-video/233066-wmp-12-wont-play-srt-subtitles.html). However the KMP player is also a good one which works like a champ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version of DirectVobSub and try changing your `.srt` to a `.sub` file. It worked for me.

I got it through this [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/this-is-how-you-can-add-external-subtitles-on-windows-media-player/).

Answer (score 1):

What's the file type of the video file you're trying to show subtitles for?

On which version of WMP and Windows? If you're running the 64-bit WMP, you'll need the 64-bit version of DirectVobSub as well.

Comment: Which is gettable via?

Comment: The x64 version can be downloaded at http://www.free-codecs.com/directvobsub_download.htm

Answer (score 1):

Change your subtitle file to exact name as your media name but keep the extension.

Example: 2 files are `abc.avi` and `xyz.srt`.

Change `xyz.srt` to `abc.srt`.

Now play the `abc.avi` in Windows Media Player. Right click on the playing windows, check the subtitle setting.

Comment: They said they already tried that: *I've followed the instructions in this, by installing DirectVobSub and **renaming the srt file to match the video filename***.

Comment: Which codec pack did you install? I'm using K-Lite mega codec pack.

Comment: @NamPhung, That's what I installed and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: So why don't you use Home Cinema Player?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to that problem is [Local Subtitles for WMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wmpsub/). It does not brak codecs pipeline.