# Subtitles in VLC are wrong

Tags: windows-7, video, vlc-media-player, encoding, subtitles

I have an .MKV file and the subtitles are incorrect

[image: subitltes caption]

I tried with different encondings as [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/441910/subtitles-in-vlc-are-displayed-as-question-marks) states, but I with no luck.
The subtitles are embedded inside the file so I can't open them in notepad++ to verify if they are ok..

What else can I do ? Since there are many files, and they all have the same issue, I don't think there was a problem when downloading them.

This is on Windows 7, VLC Version 2.2.1

Thanks in Advance

**Update**

I downloaded another player, Media Player Classic Home Cinema and it works fine there. So far I am watching the videos there, as a workaround..
Does this mean that my vlc is missing some codec for the subtitleS?

Comment: Maybe you don't have the correct font installed?

Comment: the VLC is configured to show the subtitles as Arial.. shouldn't I see the subtitles with that font ?